# AES_DECRYPTION on nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, encryption, aes

I created sample test table with aes encryption 256 bit, my steps as below description.

```
SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-ecb';
```

Insert data

```
INSERT INTO test_aes ( des_one, des_two ) 
values ( aes_encrypt('react', 'key'), aes_encrypt('china', 'key'));
```

View data from below query

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(des_one, 'key') as char) as des_one, 
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(des_two, 'key') as char) as des_two from test_aes;
```

Then I created nodejs project and added sequelize.
My issue is I can successfully retrieve data by executing select query, but in nodejs project I retrieved data as null values.

Nodejs code

```
const encryptTwo = await sequelize.query( "SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(des_one, 'key') as char) 
 as des_one from test_aes;" );
console.log('encryptTwo', encryptTwo[0]);
```

What I am missing,

Even tried with below link scenarios
[MySql WorkBench AES 256 Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831239/mysql-workbench-aes-256-decryption)

Same issue happening. Any suggestions ?
Thank you